# Site redirects to humbertech.com if accessed from search engine

Tags: website, search-engine

I asked this on stackoverflow but they pointed me here. So this is a copy/paste from that question...

I can normally visit my website via url. It all works fine.

But when I find it on google the link takes me to this url: http://humbertech.com/includes/domit/xml_domits_rss.php

This humbertech.com must be some kind of provider of some services that google uses i guess...

I also added my website to my Google Webmaster account, where it says there are no errors found on it which I was expecting.

I may have to contact google but they only have robots, not real people you can talk to.. :(

The site is written in php (apache).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is provider of any services Google uses.

The first result for Google search on that link gives me this page, this seems to be a malicious redirect.

http://evuln.com/labs/humbertech.com/

Your site might be infected with some malware, check your .htacces and php files for any redirects.

Also I think this would be more suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

You can try this two online scanners [sucuri.net](http://sucuri.net/) and [unmaskparasites.com](http://www.unmaskparasites.com/) to scan the site, and if you have root access, you can run maldet and clamscan on server to scan the site root folder

Comment: Yes. If the link on Google points to your domain and you end up being redirected somewhere else, the site **is** infected with something.

Comment: hm... but I would expect that google webmaster could detect this..

Comment: You can try this two online scanners http://sucuri.net/ and http://www.unmaskparasites.com/, and if you have root access, you can run maldet and clamscan on server to scan the site root folder.

Comment: @user568021: It doesn't  matter if GWT detects it or not (BTW, it's not a malware scanner, its' meant to help you optimize your site for Google), if you have a redirect on your site that you don't want and didn't create, you have a problem. Also, the evuln.com link Alen gave is pretty much self explanatory. Read [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) and act!

Comment: thanks guys... I actually looked into link you provided, but don't have time for this. I can't find the redirect in .httaccess or template files so I'll just remove the entire website.

Comment: @user568021: This is not nearly enough. You have to find out how the site was compromised and make sure your system is clean, otherwise you might end up with the same problem again.